# Weceem plugin not rendering javascript -Grails 2.3.7

Tags: grails, grails-2.3, weceem

I just got weceem-plugin (1.2) installed with Grails 2.3.7. Everything runs fine except javascript does not get rendered - it just shows up as raw text. I have confirmed all the static resources(css,images,js) are loaded. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved without rebuilding existed plugin. You can try to update your Config.groovy in your application. Please, check the demo application for Weceem on GitHub, here you can find Config.groovy  https://github.com/jCatalog/weceem-app/blob/master/grails-app/conf/Config.groovy . The application is on grails-2.3.7. Especially check setting:

`grails.resources.adhoc.excludes = ['/plugins/weceem-1.2']`

also such your settings as

`grails.views.default.codec= "none"`

`grails.views.gsp.codecs.scriptlet = "none"`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I rebuilt the plugin with the grails version I was using. Basically downloaded a copy from github, edited the dependencies to reflect the versions that my grails version comes with by default. It runs fine now - i hope it helps someone.